# Apache PHP script can't connect to remote database/ODBC/MySQL but works from command line

Tags: php, windows, apache, odbc

Using Windows Vista system with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.

I have a script that tests connections to various ODBC and MySQL databases.
When the script runs from Apache loaded in a browser window it cannot connect to any remote ODBC or MySQL databases. Local databases work fine. Socket connection also does not work.

When I run from the command prompt, all connections are OK.

When testing the connection in the ODBC control panel, they also work fine. Other applications on different systems on our network can connect to these databases.

Also, I am able to run this script from a browser window served from Apache installed under Windows on another system in a remote location.

The Windows Apache server system has the firewall disabled, but it is behind a network firewall/proxy. Although since the script works in command line, so I don't think its a firewall issue.

I have seen solutions for this but they are for Linux systems, I can't find anything for Windows machines.

Can this be some setting in the php.ini or http.conf files? Is this some Windows setting?

Here is the code

```
$lmSock = fSockOpen('www.server.com',80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if(!$lmSock) {
echo("Can't open Remote socket<br />\n");
}
else {
echo("Remote Socket Success<br />\n");
}    

$odbcConn = odbc_connect('remote.mysql','','');
if(!$odbcConn) {
    echo("Cannot Connect To ODBC remote.mysql Server<br />\n");
}
else {
  echo("ODBC remote.mysql Connection success<br />\n");
}

$odbcConn = odbc_connect('local.sql','','');
if(!$odbcConn) {
    echo("Cannot Connect To ODBC local.sql Server<br />\n");
}
else {
  echo("ODBC local.sql Connection success<br />\n");
}

$toyConn = odbc_connect('remote.sql','','');
if(!$toyConn) {
    echo("Cannot Connect To ODBC remote.sql Server<br />\n");
}
else {
  echo("ODBC remote.sql Connection success<br />\n");
}

$mysqlConn = mysql_connect('server.address','login','pass');
if(!$mysqlConn) {
    echo("Cannot Connect To MYSQL server.address Server<br />\n");
}
else {
  echo("MYSQL server.address Connection success<br />\n");
}
```

Comment: Might help if you provide the actual mysql_connect error ...

Comment: Your code is all over the place --- @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Comment: This is not the actual code, the server addresses/passwords have been removed. The code works when run from command line, but in the browser only the connection to a local server works.

Comment: Are you specifying port 3306 for your remote MySQL connection?

Comment: Do this: start > run > cmd: type without quotes 'php -i -vv >> %userprofile%/Desktop/php.txt' open that and look at your odbc settings.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is to make sure that your connection is not being blocked by Windows Firewall. Try temporarily disabling it just to test.

[Turn Windows Firewall on or off](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Turn-Windows-Firewall-on-or-off)

If that does not help, you may want to try downloading WAMP to see if there is something wrong with your installation. I am not suggesting you replace your existing installation (although you might want to if it works), I am suggesting this to try to determine if there is something wrong with the installation, or your OS.

[WAMP Download](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: The windows firewall is off. The connections are only having problems from Apache, trying to connect through ODBC control panel, or from command line all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was our company firewall. (Microsoft ISA Server 2000).

This firewall uses a utility  (ISA Client) installed on our internal systems including the server all this is running on.

It seems to me that the command line PHP scripts and ODBC control panel work through this client. Unfortunately for some reason Apache does not.

Resolved this by using the MySQL proxy application, it mirrors the remote database to a local IP address. The proxy application runs from the command line and seems to work with the firewall client.